# How to send an UDP message for an array of clients (java)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp

My question is how do i send an UDP message for an array with a list of IP's connected to the server in TCP sockets?

the code i did (just the server application, the sending part):

```
DatagramSocket socketCliente = new DatagramSocket();       
InetAddress[] IP = InetAddress.getAllByName(socketLigacao.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());   
byte[] enviaMensagem = new byte[1024];        
enviaMensagem = mensagemCliente.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < IP.length; i++){
DatagramPacket enviaPacote = new DatagramPacket(enviaMensagem, enviaMensagem.length, IP[i],     3790);
socketCliente.send(enviaPacote)
```

The code i did are just working in localhost (tested in netbeans output), when I run in different machines the client don't show any output, and i'm sure that the problem is in this part of code that i posted...

Any help would be apreciated, if tou need any more information please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: You've done it. What's the question?

Comment: the problem is that the code I did just works in localhost and with one machine (tested in netbeans output), when I run the application in different machines the clients don't show any output and that lets me think that the code i did isn't correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. **The problem is with the networking.**

In your current code, you are trying to send UDP packets to several clients at their corresponding IP addresses and a port (3790).

This worked while you were on localhost as the client IP and port were not mapped to a different one.
While you were on the local host, you simply played with the local IP and a local port to the machine.

In practical scenario, things are different. The clients are connected to a router, and precisely a firewall between the internet and your client.

The router creates a mapping to reach out the client machine. The local IP and port of the client are mapped to the external IP (the IP which the router gets by the ISP) and an external port(which identifies the client process). The local IP and port are allotted by the router to the client. This is called **Network Address Translation(NAT)**.

The router maintains a routing table to route the packets from source to destination.

By default, it allows all TCP packets to enter or leave the system after a successful connection.

But in case of UDP packets, the router allows only outgoing packets(packets leaving the network to some other network) and blocks the incoming packet.

It allows UDP packets only from those address to enter the network, to which a packet was sent by the client earlier(as sending a packet creates an entry in the router table). In other words, the router allows only those packets whose IP and port entry is available in the routing table.

**Example**:

> Consider a client machine "A" connected to a router. Let the router
> has an external IP w.x.y.z provided by the ISP. When the client
> initiates a UDP packet, let the router assign it an external port say
> 55000. To reach the client machine, the router will allot it a local IP say 192.168.1.62 and some port 3790(or define by the client
> process). The router creates a mapping of this internal or local IP
> and port to the external IP and port respectively. This can be a
> possible mappding:

```
External IP:port    <-------------->    Local IP:port

   w.x.y.z:55000    <-------------->    192.168.1.62:3790
```

> This depends on the type of NAT scheme the router uses. So, in order
> to let the clients receive packets from some machine external to the
> network, the machine on the other side must send the packets to the
> external IP and port of the client allotted by the router while
> initiating the UDP packet. The router will then forward it to the
> local IP and port of the client.

In your case, you are sending packets but these packets are blocked by the router which comes in between the internet and the client. **You need to send packets to the external IP and port of the client.**

You will need to implement **UDP hole punching** for this. Although it does not guarantee to work on all types of NAT.

> Or better to say that please read more about networking conditions,
> about how these mappings are done in the router, etc.

Here are some of the sources:

[Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

[UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

[RFC 4787 NAT Behavioral Requirements UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787)

[RFC 5128 P2P across NAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128)

Comment: Thank you Kunjan! your answer was very explanatory about how the UDP communication works through different networks, but in my case that is not a problem because i'm working in a LAN. Furthermore, the network is working well because i have done other simple applications with TCP and UDP protocols and these are working properly. Once more, thank you for your time!